# Service and Wake Lock Policy

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, wakelock

As stated by the AlarmManager docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP

> This means that the phone will in some cases sleep as soon as your onReceive() method completes. If your alarm receiver called Context.startService(), it is possible that the phone will sleep before the requested service is launched. To prevent this, your BroadcastReceiver and Service will need to implement a separate wake lock policy to ensure that the phone continues running ***until*** the service becomes available.

From what I've seen and read here: 
http://www.androidguys.com/2009/04/02/wake-up-with-the-alarm/
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/SystemServices/Alarm/src/com/commonsware/android/syssvc/alarm/WakefulIntentService.java

That guys holds onto the wake lock ***through*** the service not just ***until*** it becomes available. So my question is, will a service allow the CPU to sleep if it does not have a wake policy running ***through*** the service?

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is, will a service allow the CPU to sleep if it does not have a wake policy running through the service?

Of course. Think of a laptop that sleeps when one closes its lid (the silly default). Some method somewhere will be interrupted - be it the main() method of the currently running application

Comment: Can you tell me how to implement the wake lock policy in a service or broadcastreceiver? Thanks.